# Open a Specific URL page in WebView when the Fire base based Push Notification is clicked?

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-webview

I created an android app using Webview and implemented the Firebase push notification. I also pass the URL in the custom data field in firebase message console when sending the push notification.

But when I click the notification, it directly opens the homepage of my app. How can I make it open the specific page in the app when I click the notification ?

I used following code but it still opens a opan page instead of specific page. please suggest

This is my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://exampe.blogspot.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
    }
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService Class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        // Extract the URL from the notification data
        String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");

        // Create a PendingIntent to open the URL in the webview
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Build and show the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default_channel")
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the URL from `Intent` which you have passed from `PendingIntent` like below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    String url = getIntent.getStringExtra("url");

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebView.loadUrl(url);

    WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: then how to load  webview url  

mywebView.loadUrl("https://exampe.blogspot.com/");

Comment: You can add condition for the if user is not empty show URL else pass you custom url.

Comment: i tried the code but not working 
 String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
        if (url != null) {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            // Load default URL if no URL is received from the notification
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl(DEFAULT_URL);

Comment: any update here pls ?